# In Overleaf tables, what are the columns separated by?

Tags: tables

By using `\begin{tabular}{c c c}` for a table, what are the columns separated by? Are they separated by tabs?

Comment: There is a horizontal space of 6pt on each side of a cell, which makes a total of 12 pt between consecutive columns.

Comment: Latex is about typesetting, so no tabs are needed. Unlike in an ASCII-editor or HTML positions for textboxes are calculated and filled with text, e.g. for the second cell. Though factually wrong, in analogy think of calculating positions of pixels in a bitmap image.

Comment: Distance between column content its border is name `\tabcolsep`. As alredy said @Bernard, its value is 6pt. You can change it by `\setlength\tabcolsep{<desired distance>}`. BTW, this is defined in LaTeX and has nothing with Overleaf.

Comment: And in the TeX source code, you'll separate columns with an ampersand `&` (but if that answers your question, you may want to read up on LaTeX tables in general).

Comment: I am writing up a document where the columns of tables are required to be aligned by tabs. (It's an Elsevier article if anyone is familiar with.) I'm not sure if the 12 pt between columns is acceptable or not. but if I want to be exact, how to specify the column separator to be tabs?

Comment: overleaf is not involved here, they are just hosting a latex system for you.  It is not clear what you mean by "tab" here, columns are separated by a distance, not a character.  tab characters are treated as normal spaces by tex